# R plyr ddply - How to leave one or more variables out from result?

Tags: r, plyr

Say I want to sum my cost over the different types of sources, but I want to leave one specific source out from the operation. To get a cost breakdown over all sources I use

```
ddply(data, .(Source), summarize, Cost= sum(Cost))
```

But let's say out of all the different types of sources there's one I want to exclude from this - what's the easiest way to achieve this? I can just subset the result, but is there a way to do this through ddply directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example subset the data you pass into `ddply`:

```
ddply(subset(data, Source != "abc"), .(Source), summarize, Cost= sum(Cost))
```

Or

```
ddply(subset(data, !Source %in% c("abc", "def")), .(Source), summarize, Cost= sum(Cost))
```

Of course you could use `[` instead of `subset`.

Or you could give dplyr a try:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(!Source %in% c("abc", "def")) %>% group_by(Source) %>% summarise(Cost = sum(Cost))
```

Or with data.table (not tested..):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[!Source %in% c("abc", "def"), .(Cost = sum(Cost)), by=Source]
```

Comment: Never said thank you for this, I use this all the time now. Thanks!